# get all days and dates from month and year using moment.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, momentjs

The below code's are getting from moment.js document

```
moment().date(Number);
moment().date(); // Number
moment().dates(Number);
moment().dates(); // Number
```

But the input `parameter` data type is number instead of *short month name and year* which is mine requirement inputs.

Below is my input format like an array object

```
`$scope.allMonths = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun",
"Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Act", "Nov", "Dec"];
$scope.Year=2017;// `
```

**So I have month and year, Now I want to get all days and date by using moment.js**

---

### Update:

> I got the exact result by using normal javascript in my below [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29306976/2218635). But still am unable to find the solution by using moment.js

Comment: You can map the name of the month to the coinciding number.

Comment: How? can you show me the code?

Comment: I looked at the docs for moment.js, and those functions are for setting and getting the current day of the month. So I don't think that is what you are looking for. Also, I'm really not sure what you are looking for. What do you mean by "all days and date from a short month name"?

Comment: I have update my question. please now see my question.

Comment: I'm still not understanding... what is the exact output you are expecting?

Comment: See the link http://www.tfs-timetracker.com/

Comment: I have the year and month, but i can't get the days and dates from the month and year. does make sense?

Comment: I don't think that is something that momentjs does. You'll have to write a custom method to do that. The only idea I have is to create a Date object for the first day of the given month and year, get the day of the week from that, and then derive the rest of the days for the month from that first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got it by javascript

```
//selected year
$scope.selectedYear = function (value) {
            $scope.selectedYearValue = value;// 2011
        }

   //get days and date from  a month and year
        $scope.getDaysArray = function (month) {// month count is 2              
            var names = ['Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat'];
            var date = new Date($scope.selectedYearValue, month - 1, 1);
            $scope.DayAndDate = [];
            while (date.getMonth() == month - 1) {
                result.push({ "Date": date.getDate(), "Day": names[date.getDay()] });
                $scope.DayAndDate.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
            }
        }
```

now the result is

```
js> getDaysArray(2012)
["1-wed", "2-thu", "3-fri", "4-sat", "5-sun", "6-mon", "7-tue",
 "8-wed", "9-thu", "10-fri", "11-sat", "12-sun", "13-mon", "14-tue",
"15-wed", "16-thu", "17-fri", "18-sat", "19-sun", "20-mon", "21-tue", 
"22-wed", "23-thu", "24-fri", "25-sat", "26-sun", "27-mon", "28-tue",
"29-wed"]
```

**but i don't want it by using JavaScript instead of moment.js** .

Comment: So this is the result you want? But you want to do it with moment?

Comment: Yes, I am waiting for moment.js ..

Answer (score 5):

- [Parse](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/) the date based on the month and year
- Loop through the month, [formatting](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/) each day into an array.

```
function getMonths(month,year){
    var ar = [];
    var start = moment(year+"-"+month,"YYYY-MMM");
    for(var end = moment(start).add(1,'month');  start.isBefore(end); start.add(1,'day')){
        ar.push(start.format('D-ddd'));
    }
    return ar;
}
console.log(getMonths('Mar',2011))
```